# Substring in a PowerShell function

Tags: function, powershell, substring

I've got a function which works fine.
It pulls the first character of the firstname and the whole lastname from a text box in a PowerShell GUI and then it creates a sAMAccountName from both.
Now I need only the first 8 characters from the generated sAMAccountName.

Here is the function

```
Function Set-sAMAccountName {
    Param([Switch]$Csv=$false)
    if(!$Csv)
        {
        $GivenName = $txtFirstName.text
        $Surname = $txtLastName.text
        }
    else{}
    Switch($XML.Options.Settings.sAMAccountName.Style | Where{$_.Enabled -eq $True} | Select -ExpandProperty Format)
        {
        "FirstName.LastName"    {"{0}.{1}" -f $GivenName,$Surname}
        "FirstInitialLastName"  {"{0}{1}" -f ($GivenName)[0],$Surname}
        "LastNameFirstInitial"  {"{0}{1}" -f $Surname,($GivenName)[0]}
        Default                 {"{0}.{1}" -f ($GivenName)[0],$Surname}
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thx a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

`Substring` works like that:

you pass the index of where you want to start

you pass the index of where you want to end the reading of the substring (if your not passing anything it will go until the end of the string's length)

so in your case it will be start reading at index `0` end reading at index `8`:

```
$str = "a simple string"
$newString = $str.Substring(0,8)
```

I  really recommend to read about `string` manipulation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692804.aspx)

Comment: "you pass the index of where you want to end" - wrong! The second argument is the *length* of the desired substring, not the end index

Comment: where you want to end the reading... edited for better understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it now!

I've added the **-and** condition to check the length of the sAMAccountName and said **-lt 8** and it's working now. The sAMAccountName is now 8 characters long.

This was the code before:

```
    $txtName_TextChanged={
    Write-Verbose "Creating required account fields"

    if ($XML.Options.Settings.DisplayName.Generate -eq $True) {$txtDN.Text = Set-DisplayName}
    if ($XML.Options.Settings.sAMAccountName.Generate -eq $True) {$txtsAM.Text = (Set-sAMAccountName)}
    if ($XML.Options.Settings.UPN.Generate -eq $True) {$txtUPN.Text = Set-UPN}
}
```

And after the change:

```
    $txtName_TextChanged={
    Write-Verbose "Creating required account fields"

    if ($XML.Options.Settings.DisplayName.Generate -eq $True) {$txtDN.Text = Set-DisplayName}
    if ($XML.Options.Settings.sAMAccountName.Generate -eq $True -and $txtsAM.Text.Length -lt 8) {$txtsAM.Text = (Set-sAMAccountName)}
    if ($XML.Options.Settings.UPN.Generate -eq $True) {$txtUPN.Text = Set-UPN}
}
```